# How to store value from a textbox into a javascript variable in a asp.net vb.net application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am working with asp.net; vb.net; java script. and want to store some values in the java script variable.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/_resx/E4.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="new.aspx.vb" Inherits="E4_Jobs_new" ValidateRequest="false" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/_controls/ucApplicationQuestions.ascx" TagPrefix="Application"
TagName="Questions" %>

  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
     <script type="text/javascript">
         var id = '<%= ModeID%>',
             mode = '<%= Mode%>',
             employer = '<%= Employer.Name %>',
             jobtitle = document.getElementById(<%= txtTitle.ClientID%>);

     </script>

     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTitle" Display="None" ErrorMessage="xx" ValidationGroup="NewJob" EnableViewState="False" />
         <div class="form-element">
              <input type="text" id="txtTitle" runat="server" maxlength="64" /></div>
</asp:Content>
```

Now as you can see in my code i have four java script variables.

```
id, mode, employer  & jobtitle
```

for the first 3 variable i am getting the correct result.
but for the last one i am not being able to get the correct result.

what i want is the input value in the text box will be in the fourth variable (before submitting the form).

i am trying to get the value by using `document.getelementbyid` 
and store it like

```
jobtitle = document.getElementById(<%= txtTitle.ClientID%>)
```

i have also tried

```
jobtitle = document.getElementById(<%= txtTitle.ClientID%>).value
```

but its not working. (and also the editor doesnot suggest me to use value. it suggests valueof)

when i see the source code i see the following result

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = '609',
        mode = 'draft',
    employer = 'MyPeopleBiz',
    jobtitle = document.getElementById(ctl00_MainContent_txtTitle);

</script>
```

and the source code for the textfield is like this

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtTitle" type="text" id="ctl00_MainContent_txtTitle" maxlength="64" />
```

how do i get the value and store the result in the javascript variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`jobtitle = document.getElementById("<%= txtTitle.ClientID%>").value;`

Comment: Not working .. in the source code i get this    jobtitle = document.getElementById("+ctl00_MainContent_txtTitle+").value;

Answer (score 0):

If this code is running server side, hence before the DOM is generated then you will not be able to access any DOM nodes as they will not yet exist.

Instead you could put the `<%= txtTitle.ClientID%>` into a hidden field on the page, and then use jQuery's `$(document).ready()` functionality to obtain the result of the hidden field and use it as required (i.e. assigning it to your global variable `jobtitle`.

Comment: The value for txtTitle is not fixed. it will be the value given by the user. How do I store the value in hidden field.? pardon me if I dont understand the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a [0] before the .value:

var jobtitle = document.getElementById("<%= txtTitle.ClientID%>")[0].value;